# Inclusion of a header-only library to multiple files producing a linker error

Tags: c++, linker, header-files, header-only

I'm using a header-only single-file "library" to load `.obj`-models from a file into a graphics program. A simple linker error has popped up:

> LNK2005 "Info here" already defined in main.obj

Now I know what this means and normally I'd proceed with moving the implementation to a separate file. However, this is a file provided by someone way smarter than I, and so relying on authority I'd expect the thing to work.

It only complains about a vector multiplication operator overload and a single function among loads of other functions:

```
glm::vec3 operator*(const float& left, const glm::vec3& right){
    return glm::vec3(right.x * left, right.y * left, right.z * left);
}

bool inTriangle(glm::vec3 point, glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
    // Starting vars
    glm::vec3 u = tri2 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 v = tri3 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 w = point - tri1;
    glm::vec3 n = glm::cross(u, v);

    float y = glm::dot(glm::cross(u, w), n) / glm::dot(n, n);
    float b = glm::dot(glm::cross(u, w), n) / glm::dot(n, n);
    float a = 1 - y - b;

    // Projected point
    glm::vec3  p = (a * tri1) + (b * tri2) + (y * tri3);

    if (a >= 0 && a <= 1
        && b >= 0 && b <= 1
        && y >= 0 && y <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Is there something special about these functions?

The file is from [OBJ Loader](https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader), which I have modified just to use the `glm` vectors and utilities I'm currently using elsewhere.

Comment: I had a quick look at that library. File a bug report (an issue, since it's on github). It's unusable as a header-only library. There are a lot of functions that aren't marked as `inline` (`inline` just means that the definition can be in a header file without causing linker errors), so the linker will find multiple definitions and give you an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something special about these functions?

Yes, they were not marked as `inline` like all the other free functions in the `algorithm` namespace.

When you define a function in a header file you need to mark it as inline so that it can be defined in multiple translation units (included in multiple source files) without error.

Comment: Ah! Another day, another keyword finally making sense :D Thank you!

Comment: @Felix You're welcome.  You might want to raise an issue with the library about this.

Comment: @Felix I have no idea what typo you are talking about ;)